# What is the good way of pagination with ASP.NET MVC2 + LINQ-to-Entities?

Tags: performance, linq-to-entities, pagination

I created an internal website that use lots of data from a SQL Database (1 282 727 lines for now (~800MB), growing each minutes), I use this code (LINQ to entities) to render the page with pagination :

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
    {
        IronViperEntities db = new IronViperEntities();
        db.Connection.Open();
        DbTransaction transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
        var messages = (from globalView in db.GlobalViews orderby globalView.MessageId descending select globalView).Skip(page*perPage).Take(perPage);
        transaction.Commit();
        db.Connection.Close();
        ViewData["page"] = page;
        ViewData["messages"] = messages;
        return View();
    }
```

Everything works fine except that it looks like bigger is the page number, slower is the page, when I show the page 2, it take ~700ms (90% is from latency), when I show page 6354, it take 4280ms...

Is that normal ? If not, how to fix it ?

The website use ASP.NET MVC2, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

EDIT: Here is an example of SQL Query generated by LINQ To Entities :

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Extent1].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], 
[Extent1].[MessageUuid] AS [MessageUuid], 
[Extent1].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], 
[Extent1].[MessagePostDate] AS [MessagePostDate], 
[Extent1].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], 
[Extent1].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], [Extent1].[MessageUuid] AS 
[MessageUuid],     [Extent1].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], [Extent1].[MessagePostDate] AS
[MessagePostDate], [Extent1].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName],
[Extent1].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], [Extent1].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid], row_number() OVER
(ORDER BY [Extent1].[MessageId] DESC) AS [row_number]
FROM (SELECT 
  [GlobalView].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], 
  [GlobalView].[MessageUuid] AS [MessageUuid], 
  [GlobalView].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], 
  [GlobalView].[MessagePostDate] AS [MessagePostDate], 
  [GlobalView].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], 
  [GlobalView].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
  [GlobalView].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], 
  [GlobalView].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid]
  FROM [dbo].[GlobalView] AS [GlobalView]) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 656700
ORDER BY [Extent1].[MessageId] DESC
```

Comment: do you mean to set the page to 0 in the method arguments?

Comment: I wonder if this isn't more a database question than a ASP.NET MVC question. Is it worth taking a look at the SQL being generated to get this data and ask the question "why is this SQL query running so slow on my database?" Are you maybe running into a limitation of the Express Edition of SQL server since you have so many rows?

Comment: why are you creating a DB transaction on a strictly read-only operation?

Comment: @Jim: the page argument is by default 0, or defined in the URL mapping

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you are creating a db transaction for a read-only operation as Kirk Woll said in your comments. The other question is why are you opening the db connection? It looks like you are using the Entity Framework which means you don't need any of that. Just use the Read Only operation to populate an object and then call object.SaveChanges(); This will persist the changes back to the database. For example:

```
MyProjectEntities db = new MyProjectEntities();
Person person = db.People.Where(x => x.Name == "John Doe").First();
person.Name = "ChangedObjectData";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Modify your action method to look like this and tell me if it still accomplishes what you are looking for.

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
{
     IronViperEntities db = new IronViperEntities();
     var messages = (from globalView in db.GlobalViews orderby globalView.MessageId descending select globalView).Skip(page*perPage).Take(perPage);
     ViewData["page"] = page;
     ViewData["messages"] = messages;
     return View();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to create the transaction, because there is another application (using RAW SQL) that puts data in the database at the same time, and if I don't make a transaction, I randomly get Deadlocks :(